French movie with a Russian roulette climax
I'm looking for an old (40s - 50s) French medieval adventure movie. I think the main hero is Jean Marais but recently I began to doubt this, because I haven't found anything similar in his filmography.
The final scene had Russian roulette between the hero and the antagonist for the dame, with two glasses of wine (poisoned and still). The antagonist poisoned both glasses, but the hero survived because he had immunity to the poison. He was also a very skilled fencer and raider and had outstanding strength and intelligence.

This sounds like "The Princess Bride" (1987), and Cary Elwes could be mistaken for Jean Marais.  Here is the poisoned-wine scene: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_eZmEiyTo0

@WillFeldman Oh my! I remembered the movie to be black-white and much older... Thanks a lot! You should probably make an answer from your comment.

This sounds like The Princess Bride, (1987).  Cary Elwes looks something like Jean Marais, and his character defeats Mandy Patinkin in a sword-fight, Andre the Gaint in hand-to-hand combat, and Wallace Shawn in a battle of wits.  (The battle of wits is the poisoned-wine scene.)
